# Pandas csv import first row

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multiple-columns

I need help importing a csv into the python using pandas 0.7.3
I can get the data into python but the columns are read in as one column. See example
below.

```
In [12]: data=pd.read_csv(file)'
In [13]: data[:3]
Out[13]:
        Area    Circ.   AR      Round   Solidity
0  1    31650   0.368   2.973   0.336   0.683
1   2   6875    0.836   1.181   0.847   0.924
2  3    12850   0.767   1.543   0.648   0.902

In [14]: data.columns
Out[14]: Index([        Area    Circ.   AR      Round   Solidity], dtype=object)
```

How can I import the data so I get the following data structure

```
In [14]: data.columns
Out[14]: Index([Area, Circ., AR, Round, Solidity,], dtype=object)
```

such that

```
In [15]:data['area']
Out[15]:
31650
6875
12850
etc
```

Thanks.

Comment: show data in file, use `sep=` to define separator.

Answer (score 0):

`CSV` = Comma Separated Values - so normally pandas is searching `;` as separator.

You can use `sep=` in `read_csv` to define separator.
You can use even regular expression in definition.
For example I define separator as one or more spaces.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+')
```

---

BTW: the newest version is 0.14 - upgrade `pandas`.